# View with subviews in a uinavigationbar and uitoolbar

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uinavigationbar, title

I really need your help with this one (first post on SO -- be gentle):

I have two dynamic UIButtons which I would like to have centered in a UIView, which in turn should be centered in a UINavigationbar and UIToolbar. I can't - despite a lot of Googling - seem to figure out a proper way to do this.

This is what I've done so far:

In viewDidLoad, I add the two buttons as subviews and set the view as the UINavigationbar's titleView

```
self.myClass.viewForTitleAndButton = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 120, 32)];
[self.myClass.viewForTitleAndButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[self.myClass.viewForTitleAndButton addSubview:self.myClass.myButton];
[self.myClass.viewForTitleAndButton addSubview:self.myClass.myOtherButton];
self.navigationItem.titleView = self.myClass.viewForTitleAndButton;
```

In a method being triggered when I press certain buttons, I set the title (and bounds) of one of the buttons depending on what's clicked:

```
CGSize titleSize = [title sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont italicSystemFontOfSize:17.0]}];
CGSize screenSize = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size;
CGFloat newX = (screenSize.width - titleSize.width) / 2;
CGRect buttonFrame = self.myClass.myButton.frame;

//Removing the line below doesn't do any difference at the moment
self.myClass.myButton.bounds = CGRectMake(newX, buttonFrame.origin.y, titleSize.width+8, buttonFrame.size.height);

[self.myClass.myButton setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
NSLog(@"Title: %@", title);
//title is a NSString that changes depending on what is clicked. I am 100% sure it changes as I can see it in the log every time the method is triggered.
```

The problem is that the title of myButton is not changed. It worked before with the very same button when it was placed in a different spot and not as a subview.

Q1: What am I missing to make the title of the button change?

Q2: Is adding the buttons as subViews to a view that is then placed in the navigationbar and toolbar respectively a sound way to accomplish what I want?

This is really bugging me, any pointers in the right direction is much appreciated.

Comment: Are the bounds changing? or is this also not working?

Comment: Additional information: myButton has an outlet. I've tried with both a weak and a strong reference.

Comment: @Merlevede: I added a purple backgroundColor to myButton, and the purple area remains the same size.

Comment: It seems like your `myButton` outlet is not linked to the button in Interface Builder

Comment: At first, I suspected that as well, but I just triple checked and it is indeed linked. The title of the button was changed before when it wasn't part of viewForTitleAndButton.

Comment: Maybe you could try to `NSLog` the value of `self.myClass.myButton` just to make sure it's not null

Comment: @Merlevede: thanks for the advice. The button is apparently null, but I don't know why. Any idea what it could be?

Comment: Hmmm, could you check if it is null before adding it to `viewForTitleAndButton`?

Comment: Good idea. I added one log message before and one after adding it as a subView. The button exists both before and after as this is logged:

"<UIButton: 0x15666a80; frame = (0 0; 135 34); opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x15666b70>>"

It seems it's not until myButton is clicked that it turns into null.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can add a button which is already an outlet of a view controller. Thinking in another way, a button(view) can only has one superview.

Create button dynamically for the title view.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIView *iv = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 160, 44)];
    iv.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    titleButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    titleButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 120, 44);
    [titleButton setTitle:@"test" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [titleButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [iv addSubview:titleButton];
    self.navigationItem.titleView = iv;
}

//some event to change the button title
- (void)click:(UIButton *)button
{
    [titleButton setTitle:@"I changed" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Danyun. Do you have any suggestions on other ways of doing this?

Comment: Create the button dynamically for the title view. I edited my answer.

Comment: As I have too few reputation points, I have to post this as a comment.

Q1 answered:
It wasn't adding myButton as a subView that caused it not to work. The malicious piece of code was this:

    self.navigationItem.titleView = self.myClass.viewForTitleAndButton;

This, however, makes myButton function as intended:

    self.navigationItem.titleView = self.myClass;

Q2 still remais, though.

Comment: what do you mean 'The malicious piece of code was this: self.navigationItem.titleView = self.myClass.viewForTitleAndButton'

Comment: setting that caused myButton to be null.

Comment: I think you need to combine Q1 and Q2: You should not add and outlet button as a subview, add a dynamically and then Q2 will be solved, in my opinion.